# Why is this MySQL INSERT not working in CI?

Tags: php, codeigniter

For some reason this SQL statement is not working.  Can anyone tell me why?  (This is a Codeigniter site, if that matters)

Here is my Model (where my error is pointing me to)

```
public function edit_profile($ID, $field, $new_info)
{
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET ?=? WHERE id=?";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($field, $new_info, $ID)); // <<<< LINE 42
    return $query;
}
```

And this is the error I'm getting

```
Error Number: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''first_name'='oooo' WHERE id='151'' at line 1
UPDATE users SET 'first_name'='oooo' WHERE id='151'
Filename: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MY_SITE/models/member_model.php
Line Number: 42
```

My table is called 'users', and I have a 'first_name' and 'id' column.

Ideas?

**EDIT**

Just because it seems to come up a bit I want to clarify that the variables I am passing in here have NO QUOTES OR BACKTICKS.  They are being added somewhere (and it seems like the ->query method, but I cant imagine that's true? .. dunno though, cause it's my first CI project)

Here is the controller that is passing to the model...

```
public function profileEdit()
{
    $ID = $this->the_user->id;
    $field = $this->input->post('edit_field')
    $field = strstr($field,'_edit', true);
    $new_info = $this->input->post('new_info');

    $this->load->model('Member_model');
    if( $this->Member_model->edit_profile( $ID, $field, $new_info )){
        echo 'success';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'error';
    }
}
```

Comment: the quotes around `first_name` is breaking your query

Comment: @JohnConde  I thought it might be a quote issue.  But I'm not putting those there, the variables are being dynamically assigned and the quotes are getting added in the process.  What is the better way to do what I want?

Comment: Also integers in MySQL sintax cannot be surrounded by quetes, (i.e. `WHERE id=151`)

Comment: @Epsil0neR  That does seem strange since the quotes are being added by the query function itself.  When I am getting them they are quote-free.

Comment: @Epsil0neR They can. They'll get cast from string to int by the database engine

Comment: @K.K.Smith It happened to me a few times and after removing quotes from ingegers everything worked fine, you can try it and if it will work, I`ll be happy for I could help

Comment: @Epsil0neR  thx for your help, and I changed the code a bit to reflect heXa's answer, but the quotes are still there.  I'm not adding them .. my variables are "pure".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i suggest use like this :

```
public function edit_profile($ID, $field, $new_info)
{
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET $field =? WHERE id=?"; # UPDATED (remove $this->db->escape())
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($new_info, $ID)); // <<<< LINE 42
    return $query;
}
```

if $field is not secured you can use escape functions .
EDIT :
$this->db->escape() will add quotes around variable so you will get an error again .

Comment: this is likely the problem - I don't believe you can bind a field name in MySQL using PDO.

Comment: Ok.  I was looking at the example for query bindings in the CI user guide and I thought field names could be approached the same way.

Comment: Oh oh .. I spoke too soon even with your code i get this error

                Error Number: 1054
  Unknown column ''first_name'' in 'field list'
  UPDATE users SET `'first_name'`='ooo' WHERE id='151'
  Filename: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/NOIR_FINAL/models/member_model.php
  Line Number: 45

The quotes are still there, but the variables I am passing in are definitely quote free.  (the first_name up there has single quotes inside of backticks.. it's getting interpreted strangely.)

Comment: @HeXa I'm not using *any* quotes or backticks.  When I am passing my vars (from jquery AJAX function to an AJAX controller here..)  I console.log them to inspect. They are "naked" .. there are no quotes.  I don't know where they are coming from.

Comment: try without $this->db->escape() function and without any quote or back tick . i'm not sure why you see this err .

Comment: @HeXa Hallelujah!! Without the escape() function and the backticks in your code it worked.  I'm already cleaning the variables in my controller so I dont need to here.  If you can edit your answer to get rid of the backticks and escape() I will mark yours as the solution.  thx!

Comment: From the CI User GUide > $this->db->escape() This function determines the data type so that it can escape only string data. It also **automatically adds single quotes around the data** so you don't have to: